# Check for particular value in all nodes present in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have this kind of structre in my `FirebaseDatabase`. I want to check if `key` with value `9028571487` exist in any of the node in my database. If exists then I should be able to get the value of key `mess` for that specific node where that value `9028571487` is present. I am using this code:

```
public void Check(){
    final String phone=username.getText().toString();
    ref = database.getReference().child("Users");
    Query query=ref.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(data.child(name).exists()){
                    Log.i("Present","Present");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good except the fact that you are ordering your users according to the `phone` property and your are passing to the `equalTo()` method the name. To solve this, pass to the `equalTo()` method the corresponding phone and **not** the name.

```
Query query=ref.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone);
```

**Edit:**

If your `onDataChange()` method is not even called, you might have insufficient permissions. Check the this using the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
}
```

Comment: that name actually is phone string. Still not getting result

Comment: Have you tried to actually hardcode the phone like this `Query query=ref.orderByChild("phone").equalTo("9028571487");`? Does it work this way?

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even called? If you add `Log.d(TAG, "Inside onDataChange");` inside the method, do you get the output in the logcat?

Comment: No. On data change is not called

Comment: Please see my updated answer and check the permissions.

Comment: Can you suggest me what permissions and where should I enable it ?

Comment: In your Firebase console. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565807/how-to-use-firebase-with-read-and-write-rules-as-false) out and tell me if it works.

Comment: Does `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` print something?

Comment: It does not enter in value event listener

Comment: Are you sure you have internet access on the device?