# What happens when I change firebase rules to this:

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I need to know if since the user can write code and add data to my database, can the user also take data from my database, delete data, or just see my data even though read is false and only write is true.

I basically want to know if by doing this, user can input data but not see it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565807/how-to-use-firebase-with-read-and-write-rules-as-false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use firebase with read and write rules as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565807/how-to-use-firebase-with-read-and-write-rules-as-false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

No regular user can read any data from the database.

Any user can write anything they want to anywhere in the database, including overwriting data that was written there by other users.